# BigCommerce custom javascript on checkout page not working

Tags: javascript, bigcommerce

I need to hide tax price div on checkout page.
I added javascript code to checkout.html but it doesn't find element and occurring error in console.
It seems javascript runs before element loaded.
If I run script on console, it works well.
How to solve this?
I added whole checkout.html file.
I added script at the end of html file.

```
{{#partial "head"}}

{{{ checkout.checkout_head }}}
{{{ stylesheet '/assets/css/optimized-checkout.css' }}}
{{ getFontsCollection }}

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.language = {{{langJson 'optimized_checkout'}}};
</script>

{{{head.scripts}}}

{{/partial}}

{{#partial "page"}}
<header class="checkoutHeader optimizedCheckout-header">
    <div class="checkoutHeader-content">
        <h1 class="is-srOnly">{{lang 'checkout.title'}}</h1>
        <h2 class="checkoutHeader-heading">
            <a class="checkoutHeader-link" href="{{urls.home}}">
                {{#if checkout.header_image}}
                    <img alt="{{settings.store_logo.title}}" class="checkoutHeader-logo" id="logoImage" src="{{ checkout.header_image }}"/>
                {{ else }}
                    <span class="header-logo-text">{{settings.store_logo.title}}</span>
                {{/if}}
            </a>
        </h2>
    </div>
</header>
<div style="text-align:center;padding:4px;color: #ff0000;font-size:14px;">Sales tax will be removed during step 2 for all states, except PA, TX & WA.</div>
{{{ checkout.checkout_content }}}

{{{ footer.scripts }}}

{{/partial}}

{{> layout/empty}}

***<script type="text/javascript">
       document.querySelector('[data-test="cart-taxes"]').style.display = "none"; 
</script>***
```

Answer (score 2):

The accordion layout of the Optimized One-page Checkout loads in stages, so you're correct--your JS is running before the targeted element exists. You can run your code on an interval, but a better solution would be to use something like [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes in the DOM.

Here's a tutorial on using Mutation Observer out of the box:
http://ryanmorr.com/using-mutation-observers-to-watch-for-element-availability/

But you might also check out this wrapper library, which removes a lot of the complexity of using MO: https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive

But to answer your question in a slightly different way, why not just hide the cart tax line item with CSS? That way, you don't have to worry about watching the DOM:

```
<style>
    .cart-priceItem:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: It is better to use the css together with the data attribute: `[data-test="cart-taxes"] { display: none! }` the order of the elements might change, the data-test attribute should be more stable.